# Which pin is video, audio right and left?

Tags: pi-3, audio, video

I heard that you can solder rca/3.5mm terminal blocks to the pins of the audio/video 3.5mm and connect it to a/v compatible displays and also connect the audio pins with an audio amp/4-8 ohm speaker...
I checked several sources, but many claim different Things.. Most say that the 3 pins under the 3.5mm
Are left audio, video and rifgt audio from left to right. Is that true?[image: this is the underside od the 3.5mm jack:]

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Let me know if the Q&A I think is a duplicate does not answer your question.